# Installing OSX mountain lion on virtual box

Tags: macos

I know how to install Mac OSX on virtual box using iso image. I have doe that also. But my question is installing OSX mountain lion which has been downloaded from App store, in virtual box. Since it is downloaded from app store, it tries to install when I opened that package. Also is there any way to convert App store package to iso image. The file I own is not a dmg file(I found an option to install using dmg file in virtual box).

Comment: Are u talking about accomplishing this on a Mac or a PC - Which is the primary Operating System?

Comment: If u are talking about doing it on a PC....so called Hackintosh builds, I think that is considered off topic for SuperUser

Comment: If he's downloading it from the App Store he's obviously on a Mac.  And at that point telling him how to convert the DMG to an ISO isn't violating anything.  Calm the Hackintosh stuff down.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. I have purchased and installed it in one of my iMac. I have a mac mini where Mac OS Lion is primary OS. I don't need to upgrade it into Mountain Lion because my old Xcode (4.2) and newer ones Xcode 4.5 will work on Mountain lion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple way is this:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -iso -hfs /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mountain\ Lion.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg -o OSX-10.8.iso
```

[Source](http://www.ianneubert.com/wp/2012/10/02/quickly-convert-mountain-lion-dmg-into-an-iso-file/)

That will spit out a file called `OSX-10.8.iso` that you can feed into Parallels, VMware Fusion, or VirtualBox and install from there.

Comment: Not quite... VirtualBox doesn't appear to be supporting Mountain Lion or newer. I've tried and I'm stuck with a PowerShell.